# Creating a Clone of a View in Android

Tags: android, view, clone

Is there any way that a View can be cloned in Android?  I have a reference to a complicated view which was first inflated from a layout, and then throughout the lifetime of the app was programatically edited, adding subviews, removing views etc.

I need some way to clone this view object.  At this point in time in the app, there isn't enough information available for me to re-inflate the layout and apply all of the view modifications to it programatically to get it to match the original view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15761866/884674 a workaround is at this link.

Answer (score 3):

Views can't be cloned

I think you have to implement it by yourself (constructor or method)

Can you think about another solution ? Maybe retaining the View state in another object ?

What is your case which require such a clone ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't clone views, you have to inflate your view.